# How to remove records from crossfilter cube

Tags: crossfilter

Is it possible to remove records from crossfilter cube after adding. I need to update the data of crossfilter cube without creating a new cube, from the data that is returned from my API server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossfilter version 1.3 supports [removing](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-crossfilter_remove) all records that match the current filters.